# uid : unable to do port forwarding: socat not found using helm

Tags: kubernetes, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, kubernetes-helm, minikube

I've come across an error, I'm following this github [repository](https://github.com/APGGroeiFabriek/PIVT). I am setting up the raft-tls network and When i run `helm install ./hlf-kube --name hlf-kube -f samples/scaled-raft-tls/network.yaml -f samples/scaled-raft-tls/crypto-config.yaml`. I get this error :

```
E1204 14:11:40.826765    8223 portforward.go:400] an error occurred forwarding 36311 -> 44134: error forwarding port 44134 to pod e311fa9de89b8489ed9a184835a149ef0e23b568770bd4872d16b43a439f863f, uid : unable to do port forwarding: socat not found
E1204 14:11:41.832704    8223 portforward.go:400] an error occurred forwarding 36311 -> 44134: error forwarding port 44134 to pod e311fa9de89b8489ed9a184835a149ef0e23b568770bd4872d16b43a439f863f, uid : unable to do port forwarding: socat not found
E1204 14:11:43.406081    8223 portforward.go:400] an error occurred forwarding 36311 -> 44134: error forwarding port 44134 to pod e311fa9de89b8489ed9a184835a149ef0e23b568770bd4872d16b43a439f863f, uid : unable to do port forwarding: socat not found
E1204 14:12:16.085542    8223 portforward.go:340] error creating error stream for port 36311 -> 44134: Timeout occured
E1204 14:12:40.523969    8223 portforward.go:362] error creating forwarding stream for port 36311 -> 44134: Timeout occured
E1204 14:13:05.802412    8223 portforward.go:362] error creating forwarding stream for port 36311 -> 44134: Timeout occured
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After researching for a while i found that i have to install socat on my ubuntu. Which i tried and it fixed my error. i did it by running following two commands.

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install socat
```